# How to remove values from text file with conditions

Tags: php, replace

I am trying to make a function to convert **srt** to **vtt** so I specified the differences between the two files:

srt

```
1
    00:00:05,795 --> 00:00:09,832
    Are you alright?
```

vtt

```
00:00:05.795 --> 00:00:09.832
Are you alright?
```

The difference is in the number above every line which increases by 1 in every line and the `,` in the time.

I made a function to replace `,` with `.` but I don't know how to remove all numbers from the file. I am thinking about removing the lines that is 5 letters length but maybe there is another option?

Here is what I have done:

```
function srttovtt($file){
    $str = implode("\n", file($file));
    $name = basename($file, '.srt');
    $fp = fopen('uploads/subs/' . $name . '.vtt', 'w');

    $str = str_replace(',', '.', $str); // replace comma

    fwrite($fp, $str, strlen($str));
    return $fp;
}
```

Comment: just check if the line has only numbers on it, something like `if ( preg_match('/^\d+$/', $line) ) { //remove the line }`

Comment: You should be weary of you current method of changing commas to periods. It would change `Hello, are you alright?` to `Hello. are you alright?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex to the rescue

```
$text = preg_replace('~\d+\s*(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}),(\d{3})\s*-->\s*(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}),(\d{3})~', '\1:\2:\3.\4 --> \5:\6:\7.\8', $text);
```

the first \d+ is the number that's got to go and the \s* following is every whitespace after it.

next we have the times we want modified, so we keep the numeric values in parenthesis, so we can use it later on with \1, \2 etc in the format we want.

I should have included a \s* at the start too, but then I would need a newline at the start of the formatted text, which I could not find how to insert. \n didn't seem to do the job. If anyone knows how, please edit. Though it's only visual and you don't really care for that in a subtitles file.